# The $n$th prime number is the smallest difference of products of distinct previous primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, integers

For $n\geq 2$, the smallest positive prime number formed by multiplying $2, 3, \dots, p_n$ and up to $1$ subtraction / addition

$$
2 + 3 = 5 \\
2\cdot 5 - 3 = 7 \\
3 \cdot 7 - 2\cdot 5 = 11 \\
5\cdot 11 - 2\cdot 3 \cdot 7 = 13 \\
7 \cdot 13 \cdot 2 - 3 \cdot5 \cdot 11 = 17\\
\vdots
$$
is always $p_{n+1}$.  Has this been proven?

Comment: @MCT: except for $1$...

Comment: @abiessu Good point.

Comment: That is, each of the first $n$ primes must occur in exactly one of the summands on the left (and to the first power)? While it is clear that any such number is divisible only by larger primes, I doubt that the smallest reachable number will always be $p_{n+1}$

Comment: Read [Apostol](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Apostol%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Analytic%20Number%20Theory.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stopped your examples one step too early. The smallest number $>1$ obtainable from $2,3,\ldots,17$ is 
$$2\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11-3\cdot 13\cdot 17=107.$$
(I.e., $663$ and $770$ are the factors of $N:=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots\cdot 17$ that are closest to $\sqrt N$).

Comment: I think I reached this conclusion a while back also, and found that if I didn't use all the primes up to $p_n$ that I could then get $p_{n+1}$ rather reliably.